# Unable to enable checkboxes for non admin users in JSP, liferay

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, liferay, liferay-6

I am using liferay 6. I have a view.jsp

```
<% for(int i=8; i<typeNotification.size(); i++) { %>
    <li><input style="margin:5px;" 
               name="preferencesIds" 
               type="checkbox" 
               <%= announcementsPrefTypes.contains(NotificationType.getEmailType(typeNotification.get(i))) ? "checked" : "" %> 
               value="<%= NotificationType.getEmailType(typeNotification.get(i))%>" 
        />
       <b><%=NotificationType.getTypeNotification(typeNotification.get(i)) %></b>
    </li>
<% } %>
```

The problem is if the user is not Admin the checkboxes are all disabled. When I inspect the element in the browser, I see `disabled="disabled"`, even though there is no disabled attribute.

I tried searching my entire workspace if the `name` attribute is used anywhere, but only in this jsp file the name `preferencesIds` is used.

I am also not able to overwrite the `disabled` attribute with `disabled="<%= isAdminUser%>"`. `isAdminUser` returns `false`, which does not work. But if I log in as Admin then   `disabled="<%= isAdminUser%>"` becomes `true`.

My leader says maybe there is a javascript which manipulates this checkbox's behaviour. I cannot find it, if there is one. Any idea how to override or find out what logic is causing this?

Comment: is this trying to override one of Liferay's core plugins, or your own custom plugin? Also, which *exact* version of Liferay 6 are you using? (down to the GA level please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will I found out that in the `view.jsp` there is a jsp code which redirects to another jsp file where the logic for checkboxes being disabled or not is written. Modifying the logic enabled the checkboxes.